# How to share hooks between React components with composition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, composition

I have a higher order component that adds universal functionality to a group of similar components. For the purposes of discussion, I'll call the HOC `Wrapper` and the children `CompA`, `CompB`, etc.

Wrapper is `connect`ed, and handles the interactions with the Redux store, as well as API interactions. The data it sends is owned by the wrapped children, so I pass the API/dispatch function(s) from Wrapper into the children via props. Now CompA, CompB, etc all have a `props.doStuff` function that's defined one time in Wrapper.

This is OK, but the events that determine when to call the `doStuff` function are changes of the local state in CompA, CompB, etc. So I'm copy/pasting the same `useEffect`s between the children...

```
function CompA(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect( () => {
    if (props.doStuffNow === true) {
      props.doStuff(data);
    }
  }, [props.something]);
  return <div>CompA</div>
}

function CompB(props) {
  const [differentData, setDifferentData] = useState({});
  useEffect( () => {
    if (props.doStuffNow === true) {
      props.doStuff(differentData);
    }
  }, [props.something]);
  return <div>CompB</div>
}
```

This is not D.R.Y. and I'm *really* tempted to move the `useEffect` etc into Wrapper class and allow CompA and CompB to `extend` that class.

However, the React [documentation **strongly** recommends composition over inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) using higher order components. The linked article goes so far as to say they've *never* encountered a situation in which inheritance was better than composition.

So what am I missing? Is there a way for me to make this code DRY using HOC? Can I somehow pass the `useEffect`s via props? Is the sky going to fall if I just follow my instinct: `class CompA extends Wrapper`... ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new hook called `useDoStuff` that performs the useEffect hook and then `useDoStuff(props)` wherever you need it.

```js
function useDoStuff(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({}):
  useEffect(...)
}

function CompA (props) {
  useDoStuff(props);
  ...
}

function CompB (props) {
  useDoStuff(props);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your code. Is `useDoStuff` defined inside the scope of the Wrapper class? And if so, wouldn't it need to get passed as a prop? I'm also fuzzy on how the `useState` would become available within the scope of CompA/B... won't `data` and `setData` be contained within the local scope of the function, and therefore unusable in CompA/B?

Comment: you actually often returns from your `useDoStuff` hook the variables you are interested. after all logic at your hook you do `return [data, setData]` or if you prefer `return { data, setData }`

Comment: There's another issue: The shared functionality in the hooks involves dispatching (Redux) actions. How do we make those available in the custom hook if it lives outside the scope of the `connect`ed Wrapper?

Comment: I know we _could_ pass the action-creators as props, but doesn't this start to create the same decendence chain we're trying to avoid?

Comment: You could move the state out of the hook and into the local components if that suits your needs, and pass additional arguments to the hook (whatever info the hook needs to do its thing). The idea is just to encapsulate the shared functionality in a single place and reuse it where it's needed.

Comment: @rayhatfield So you're saying passing the action creators from Wrapper to CompA via props is OK?

Comment: It's not clear to me from your pseudocode exactly what you're trying to do, or why this needs to be an effect in the first place. I don't know what action creators you're talking about. (In fairness, I haven't spent a lot of time looking at it.) If `doStuff` and `doStuffNow` are both props why not handle it all in the parent? In your example data is always an empty object. I get that this is simplified for SO, but I don't get why you're using an effect to invoke a callback with an argument from state. Why not just invoke the callback directly when state changes?